# MacOS is not saving output from say -o

Tags: macos, audio, itunes, macos-mojave, say

I have enable "Speech" on the MacOS system and run this command and hear the output:

`say  "Hello there"`

But if I try to run following command:

`say -o  "Hello, this is not working"`

The terminal seems like is doing something and hangs but creates the file

[image]

The file is there but I can play it. I open the file on iTunes but doesn't play any sound.

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong of if there is a trick to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `say -o`, you need to specify a filename to save the audio under. The command format is `say -o filename.aiff "Thing to say"`. You only specified one thing after `-o`, so the command interpreted that ("Hello, this is not working") as the filename to save under, and since there was nothing after that... it didn't actually say anything.

Solution:

```
say -o This-is-working.aiff "This is working"
```